# Read in command line arguments for folder paths and integer values

Tags: python, validation, error-handling, return-value

**The goal of this program is to:**

1. Take in 2 Folder paths
2. Take in 1 Integer Value
3. Validate both Folders are in the directory and that the Integer value is an int
4. Move a specified number of files from the source folder into the destination folder. For example, if the source folder contains 8 files I want to move the last 4 files to the destination folder.
5. **In Command line:** python main.py path1 path2 4

I'm in the testing phase of using Command line arguments instead of default value placeholders (Folder paths and integer values assigned to variables) and running through the console.

**My issue is:**

1. Everything work as intended when path1, path2, and int are all present and correct values
2. If the integer is not an int (Example, python main.py path1 path2 **string**) the program crashes and gives me errors.
3. If the program reads that the CLI arg is not an int (**num = int(sys.argv[3])**) I want to default the value to 10, but the program does not seem to do this?

**ERROR**

Blank = block out personal info
python main.py Path1 Path2 L

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blank\blank\blank\main.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\blank\blank\blank\main.py", line 66, in main
    read_args()
  File "C:\Users\blank\blank\blank\main.py", line 29, in read_args
    num = int(sys.argv[3])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'L'
```

**Main**

```
import os, sys, shutil, time

def main():
    read_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

**Code**

```
def validate_folder(folder):
    """Validates folders in working directory"""
    try:
        isDir = os.path.isdir(folder)
        return isDir
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

def validate_number(number1):
    """Validates third argument is an integer value"""
    try:
        int(number1)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def read_args():
    """Read CLI arguments"""
    source_folder = sys.argv[1]
    destination_folder = sys.argv[2]
    num = int(sys.argv[3])

    """Get main folder and archive folder and validate they are in the directory"""
    main_folder = validate_folder(source_folder)
    archive_folder = validate_folder(destination_folder)
    kept_files = validate_number(num)

    """If any of the inputs is not valid return None proceed with conditional checks"""
    if main_folder is False or archive_folder is False:
        print("Folders cannot be found")
    if main_folder is True and archive_folder is True and kept_files is False:
        num = 10
        sortFiles_and_moveFiles(source_folder, destination_folder, num)
    else:
        """If both folders are valid in the working directory pass parameters to sortFiles_and_moveFiles()"""
        sortFiles_and_moveFiles(source_folder, destination_folder, num)


def sortFiles_and_moveFiles(path1, path2, n_files):
    source_folder = path1
    destination_folder = path2
    """Get list of all files only in the given directory"""
    list_of_files = filter(lambda x: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_folder, x)), os.listdir(source_folder))

    """Sort list of files based on last modification time in descending order"""
    list_of_files = sorted(list_of_files, key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(source_folder, x)))

    """Iterate over sorted list of files and print file path, along with last modification time of file"""
    for file_name in list_of_files:
        file_path = os.path.join(source_folder, file_name)
        timestamp_str = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y :: %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file_path)))
        print(timestamp_str, ' -->', file_name)
    print("Designated files have been moved")
    
    """Move designated number of files to archive folder using slice notation."""
    for file_name in list_of_files[n_files:]:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder, file_name), destination_folder)
```

Comment: You are casting third arg to `int` in `read_args():`, just remove it

Comment: When I remove the cast and use an int as the third arg I get a new error: **for file_name in list_of_files[n_files:]:
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method**

Comment: You need to cast it to int after validation. Suppose you have passed `5`. It comes as a string. You pass it to `validate_number` and it returns True. Only here you need to cast to int (because now you are sure that it's int)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I just don't know what I need to change after the validation occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is builtin function `str.isdigit()` that returns `True` if string could be casted to `int` else `False`. Also some of your if checks can be shortened

```
if main_folder is True and archive_folder is True and kept_files is False:
```

could be replaced with simple

```
elif kept_files is False:
```

But the whole method still can be modified as follows

```
def read_args():
    """Read CLI arguments"""
    source_folder = sys.argv[1]
    destination_folder = sys.argv[2]
    num = sys.argv[3]

    """Get main folder and archive folder and validate they are in the directory"""
    main_folder = validate_folder(source_folder)
    archive_folder = validate_folder(destination_folder)

    """If any of the inputs is not valid return None proceed with conditional checks"""
    if main_folder is False or archive_folder is False:
        print("Folders cannot be found")
    elif not num.isdigit():
        num = 10
        
    else:
        """If both folders are valid in the working directory pass parameters to sortFiles_and_moveFiles()"""
        num = int(num)
    sortFiles_and_moveFiles(source_folder, destination_folder, num)
```